# Sniffing LPT Traffic

Tags: redirect, driver, sniffing, wdk, lpt

I need to intercept LPT output traffic. After a couple of hours of research, I've come to understand that the only way to do this is by writing a kernel-mode driver, more precisely a "filter driver"...?

I've downloaded the WDK, but the terminology and vast number of driver types is a little overwhelming.

I'm basically trying to understand what *kind* of driver I should be writing; my target environment is Windows XP SP2 and 3 *only*.

Some background info, if it matters: I have a bunch of legacy DOS apps that print to LPT1. I'd like to be able to capture this output and redirect this data (after GDI calls) to a modern USB (network) printer. Fortunately, the latter part of the problem's easy.

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

The sysinternals.com guys wrote an application called [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) which would let you see what was going to serial and parallel ports.

It's a few years old (11/2006 was the last update), but it should let you log what you need at least to do some of the research.

If the applications are just DOS-based, then you should be able to write a TSR program that loads before the other program and hooks the print interrupt call, and redirect it to where you want.

You might have to brush up on your 386 assembler :)

Comment: I guess this would work hardly effectively since the app was DOS-based. I would try running such app in a machine emulator like `DOSBox` or `DOSBox-X`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you could alternatively use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to sniff and log traffic.  I had a friend once do some very shifty things with moving things from a COM port to somewhere else using it.

I don't know for sure, but it might be easier than writing a driver from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think detouring CreateFile/WriteFile and friends would work, but I have a feeling that this won't work for a 16-bit app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do more than capture and forward the printer data?  If that is all you need to do, then Printfil should do the job for you.  You'll find it here: http://www.printfil.com/english.htm